# ANTLR DSL with Java interoperability

Tags: java, interop, antlr, dsl, antlr3

I have been working through the tutorial at http://bkiers.blogspot.de/2011/03/creating-your-own-programming-language.html. In short, a small language is developed that has a minimal set of arithmetic operations. "println" and "print" are directly mapped functions that call `System.out.print()`.

From this I am trying to implement my own DSL by changing some properties of the language that has been developed in that article series. I want to make `java.lang.Math` accessible from within my DSL, but can't think of a good way without having to map each function manually.

The language does not support imports whatsoever. I could introduce a new grammar rule to match `Math.<function>(<parameters>)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that by making `Math` a reserved word and make the following changes:

#### grammar additions

```
functionCall
  :  Identifier '(' exprList? ')'         -> ^(FUNC_CALL Identifier exprList?)
  |  Println '(' expression? ')'          -> ^(FUNC_CALL Println expression?)
  |  Print '(' expression ')'             -> ^(FUNC_CALL Print expression)
  |  Assert '(' expression ')'            -> ^(FUNC_CALL Assert expression)
  |  Size '(' expression ')'              -> ^(FUNC_CALL Size expression)
  |  Math '.' Identifier '(' exprList ')' -> ^(FUNC_CALL Math Identifier exprList) // added
  ;

// ...

Math : 'Math'; // added
```

#### tree grammar addition

```
functionCall returns [TLNode node]
  :  ^(FUNC_CALL Identifier exprList?)     {node = new FunctionCallNode($Identifier.text, $exprList.e, functions);}
  |  ^(FUNC_CALL Println expression?)      {node = new PrintlnNode($expression.node);}
  |  ^(FUNC_CALL Print expression)         {node = new PrintNode($expression.node);}
  |  ^(FUNC_CALL Assert expression)        {node = new AssertNode($expression.node);}
  |  ^(FUNC_CALL Size expression)          {node = new SizeNode($expression.node);}
  |  ^(FUNC_CALL Math Identifier exprList) {node = new MathCallNode($Identifier.text, $exprList.e);} // added
  ;
```

#### new Math-node class

```
package tl.tree;

import tl.TLValue;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MathCallNode implements TLNode {

    private String methodName;
    private List<TLNode> params;

    public MathCallNode(String nm, List<TLNode> ps) {
        methodName = nm;
        params = ps;
    }

    @Override
    public TLValue evaluate() {
        if(methodName.equals("sqrt")) 
            return new TLValue(Math.sqrt(params.get(0).evaluate().asDouble()));
        else if(methodName.equals("min")) 
            return new TLValue(Math.min(params.get(0).evaluate().asDouble(), params.get(1).evaluate().asDouble()));  
        // TODO implement more Math-methods
        else
            throw new RuntimeException("unknown method: Math." + methodName + "(...)");
    }
}
```

Now you don't need to implement all the separate method in their own class, but will still need to check which method is invoked in the `evaluate()` method of `MathCallNode`, of course.

If you now evaluate:

```
println(Math.sqrt(9));
println(Math.min(9, -42));
```

the following will be printed:

```
3.0
-42.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The answer is just as amazing as your whole blog series.

Comment: Thank you @halfdan, and you're welcome. Note that you may want to do some sanity checks in `evaluate()`: check the number of parameters, and perhaps the type of the provided parameters.

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely some more sophisticated way, but maybe you could have doMath("function(a,b)") and use reflection to invoke the function(a,b) in the generated code. You can even type-check the function(a,b) in this way - if java.lang.Math.function(a,b) did not exist (reflection say so), you would log type check error.

In this way only one rule should be enough (doMath).

In every case good luck ;)